# Auto Accept Invites in Google Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, calendar

I have a user in google workspace and I would like it to automatically accept all google meeting invitations sent to it.

I am looking for info in the google documentation for developers and the calendar API does not contain any class to be able to accept the invitations.

I am developing in appss script. I have managed to list all the invitations but I can not develop the automation to accept them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Google Calendar does not provide an automatic accept for Google Calendar invites. You can search for an Add-on for Google Calendar that may accomplish what you’re looking for.

This is a product limitation for Google Calendar/Google Calendar API, this request can be promoted for future development through the [Google Workspace Feature Ideas Community](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Feature-Ideas/gh-p/workspace-ideas-group) or [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/support#missing_features).